# continous pages crystal report viewer

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, crystal-reports

Can we have continuous viewing in Crystal Report Viewer, rather than clicking NextPage button ?

I am developing a win form application in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not within the viewer control itself.

You *can* export to HTML as one, single page though. HTML can be a bit wacky on the formatting, but if you format you report very strictly in columns and stay with standard fonts, you get pretty good results.

Comment: yes jeff you are right, I tried to search a lot on it..but got no pie on hand.

Comment: If you would please ACCEPT my answer, I would appreciate it.